# How to rotate labelme polygons to increase dataset size?

Tags: python, annotations, conv-neural-network

I want to increase size of my dataset. I have already annotated the images I have using the labelme tool but now i want to rotate the images. Is there away to rotate all the polygons created while annotating the image so that i don't have to again annotate the new rotated images?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please include your code attempts in your questions

Comment: I haven't tried any code. I am using labelme tool to annotate my data.